# Error in using WebClient object REST API call using C#

Tags: c#, api, rest, webclient, uploadstring

I am trying to POST an order to REST API using the below code:

```
 string URI = "https://api.myTrade.com/s1/order/" + orderId;
            string myParameters = "symbol=AAPL&duration=day&side=buy&quantity=1&type=limit&price=1";
            Console.Write("Parameters : " + myParameters + "\n");
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + token
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
                string responsebody = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
                //Console.Write("Output : " + responsebody + " ");
                dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responsebody);

                return responsebody;
            }
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
Input String was not in a correct format.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a

> ?

after the orderId before the parameters' string. Also try URL Encoding

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You @Stewart Mbofana, able to get the output. I tested with NameValueCollection using WebClient.UploadValues() method which works fine too.